# How to work in development with Discord OAuth2 live

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, discord.py

I have a django app with Discord OAuth2 authentication live on the deployed site.

With all the redirects leading back to the deployed app, what is the procedure for doing development/debugging when I can’t see the progress on the localhost?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the best solution but I..

1. Added second URI in Discord Dev Portal
2. Got second URL for that redirect
3. Added DEV_AUTH_URL_DISCORD and DEV_REDIRECT_URI variables in env.py
4. In settings.py I added conditional statement

```py
    if DEBUG == True:
        AUTH_URL_DISCORD = os.environ.get('DEV_AUTH_URL_DISCORD', '')
        REDIRECT_URI = os.environ.get('DEV_REDIRECT_URI', '')
    else:
        AUTH_URL_DISCORD = os.environ.get('AUTH_URL_DISCORD', '')
        REDIRECT_URI = os.environ.get('REDIRECT_URI', '')
```